# How to install java-common

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, java

I tried to install *jenkins* on *Ubuntu* *14.04*.

```
(venv)ubuntu@sdcw05:/usr/lib/jvm$ sudo aptitude install jenkins
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  jenkins{b} oracle-java9-installer{ab}
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 63.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 63.5 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 jenkins : Depends: daemon which is a virtual package.
 oracle-java9-installer : Depends: java-common (>= 0.24) which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     jenkins [Not Installed]
2)     oracle-java9-installer [Not Installed]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

*jenkins* have a dependency *oracle-java9-installer*

and *oracle-java9-installer* have a dependency *java-common*

How to install *java-common*? Is it a part of a some other package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install `java-common` by:

```
sudo apt-get install java-common
```

In addition

```
sudo apt-cache show java-common
```

will show you more information about the package, like the one below (some information removed for clarity):

```
Package: java-common                     
State: installed
Automatically installed: yes
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 0.52
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 299 k
Suggests: default-jre, equivs
Description: Base of all Java packages
 This package must be installed in the system if a Java environment is desired. It covers useful information for Java users in Debian
 GNU/Linux, including: 
 * The Java policy document which describes the layout of Java support in Debian and how Java packages should behave. 
 * The Debian-Java-FAQ which provides information on the status of Java support in Debian, available compilers, virtual machines, Java
   programs and libraries as well as on legal issues. 
 * Information on how to create dummy packages to fulfill java2 requirements.
Homepage: https://wiki.debian.org/Java/
```

The [suggested](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu) way to install `jenkins` is :

```
wget -q -O - https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

it is suggested that you install `openjdk-7-jre` and `openjdk-7-jdk` before the above step. To do that run:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: Thank you. I asked this question because command `sudo apt-get install java-common` doesn't work. Probably i have to find a package repository with this command.